# Course of action for accidently breaking a self imposed voluntary fast

Tags: fast-days

If one took upon themselves a voluntary fast but then forgot in the morning and had something to drink would whatvwould they do?

Some possibilities that occured to me are...

Continue fasting but make up from the morning until one broke their fast another day or add a fast day the next week.

Stop fasting and make it up another day

Continue fasting but dont make it up since it wasnt an obligation from the torah or rabbis but a voluntary fast

Another option i didnt think of

Would the initial fast being conected to a specific date on the calander make a difference. For wxample if one were to take on a fast on such and such a date each year...